# Uncommon uses of 'with'

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

It strikes me that the way we use 'with' is more complex than we may think. So I have two questions:

- Can the preposition 'with' be used to mean 'about' or 'in relation to'? (sentence a and b). 
  And also:
- Can the preposition 'with' be used as 'among' (sentence b)

> a) ... because in a moment, we need to get back to **my point with Eliot**
>
> b) He has become very popular **with the people**
>
> c) The world has not responded in ways similar to **what we have seen with
>   other** crises like the Hawaiian earthquake

These sentences are taken from public lectures 'with' well established writers and political commentators.

Comment: First point, 'about' would be sentence 'c' and sentence 'a' is neither in this context. 'a' would be functioning to join the speaker and Eliot to the same point.

Comment: @David: Thank you. And would 'b' be 'among' as I think?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you. I see you study linguistics. I would REALLY appreciate it if would share with me a book on prepositions that dead with nuances like these. I am not a beginner, though.

Comment: Yeah, a student. It doesn't necessarily mean that I am good at it. :) I can't think of a good book off of the top of my head but a quick search yeilded: https://www.englishclub.com/download/english-prepositions-list.htm It looks suitable for beginners and includes pictures but I don't want to be accountable for the quality of its content.

Comment: The trouble ***with*** little words like this is they often don't have very clearly defined *meanings* that can be exhaustively listed and learned. The exact nature of the relationship between the *point, popularity, response* to *Eliot, the people, other crises* may vary according to context/pragmatics. But in all cases the "primary" element could in principle stand alone, without the benefit of the supporting (almost *parenthetical*) reference. But OP's final sentence doesn't *quite* work - it should be ***from** well established writers...*, even if the repetition is a bit ugly.

Answer (score 1):

> *It strikes me that the way we use 'with' is more complex than we may think.*

Oh, no, on the contrary. I would suspect *with* to be very complex. Most little prepositions are. The word *on* may be one of the most complex words in English. You can start to appreciate the complexity of *with* by having a look at its [Wordnik page](https://www.wordnik.com/words/with), with dozens of definitions listed.

> Can the preposition 'with' be used to mean 'about' or 'in relation to'?

With regards to your first question, the answer is: Yes, it can. [See meaning #4](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/with).

> Can the preposition 'with' be used as 'among'?

Since I am with friends, I'll answer question one, too. Yes, it can. [See meaning #5 of *among*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/among).